# Accidentally Disabled my Touchpad

Tags: 20.04

I Accidentally disabled my Touchpad on Ubuntu 20.04. How to enable it again I don't have external mouse.

Comment: Your question should clearly explain how you managed to disable your touchpad. "Accidentally" implies a lack of intent, but doesn't help us understand the sequence of actions.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu yesterday. Its my first time. I was just checking the features and i clicked on Turn off touch pad.

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from turning it back on?

Answer (score 1):

you can open the terminal with keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T

then open the touchpad settings tab with the below command

```
gnome-control-center mouse
```

and then hit TAB until the switch on touchpad is active then hit Enter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a keyboard shortcut for this. Fn+F11 on my system (HP Omen)