# accidentally disable touchpad ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, touchpad

The shortcut for disabling the touchpad (Fn+F6) is not working on my computer.
But it doesn't matter and I never try to fix it.

Unfortunately, my toddler accidentally disabled the touchpad while he randomly push the keyboard.

I check the settings (gnome-control-center), such as shown in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356625/accidentally-disabled-my-touchpad): the touchpad is ACTIVE. enabling-disabling from control-center doesn't work.

I check the keyboard shortcut list: there is no shortcut for the touchpad.
I tried FN+ F1 to F12, it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Many thanks.

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Gnome: 3.36.8
PC: Lenovo ideapad

Here is the result of xinput (just in case):

```
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M185                             id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ALPS07AP:00 044E:120A Mouse               id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ALPS07AP:00 044E:120A Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ALPS07AP:00 044E:120A UNKNOWN             id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech M185                             id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: does `xinput --list 11` output anything relevant?

Answer (score 0):

The guideline in the link below worked for me.
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/keyboard-shortcut-for-touchpad/12114/13

Comment: That may well be an answer but what when the link no longer works? Therefore link only answers are not considered answers.